# how to reduce imagesize in iphone

Tags: iphone

Iam new to iphone currently my problem is

i displayed 6 images in image view  It was not showing images in imageview I think the imageviews are in large size

so plz send me code for this imageview.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: can you put some code so that we can check where is the problem. And you are saying that you displayed 6 images in imageView(is it in one imageView?)

Comment: I DISPLAYED 6 images in 6 image views.i implement code like this

Comment: imageview1 = [[uiimageview alloc] init];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this for image resizing:

```
- (UIImage *)rescaleImageToSize:(CGSize)size {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [self drawInRect:rect];  // scales image to rect
    UIImage *resImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resImage;
}
```